# MySql: Finding empty records with TEXT column extremely slow

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column of type MEDIUMTEXT. There are ~150 000 records in this table.

I'm trying to find records where this field is empty:

```
SELECT * FROM `q_tasks` WHERE `html`!='' limit 100
```

`html` has a MEDIUMTEXT type, and there are strings exceeding 200 KB in length.

It is extremely slow. I thought about adding an index to this column, but will it work? I could try but I'm a bit scared about what does it actually mean to add an index this kind of columns. I mean I added an index (in the same table) to a DATETIME column, it took ages and took ~3GB on my disk. I'm now left with only ~10 GB of free space:(

So I have two questions, will adding an index improve speed? And how many gigabytes (approximately) will this index take on my disk?

Comment: Indexes have their length, you can't just index anything. Even if you could, it doesn't mean that if you throw an index on something it suddenly starts working fast. What you SHOULD do is calculate a hash of the text column (say md5), add a column that stores the hash and index that column. As for how much space it will take - it's irrelevant. Databases are quick only when they can utilize RAM. The point where you start relying on HDD (more than persistence) is when your database becomes a snail.

Comment: Thanks. What about adding a new column, say "is_html_empty" - which would be 0 or 1 and then index that column? In this way I could find records with empty `html` column by searching this column. Is this a reasonable idea?

Comment: No. That index would have awful cardinality and would be useless so MySQL wouldn't use it. That means you could add such a column but simply don't index it because it won't have any effect.

Comment: OK, I'll add the md5 column, thank you!

Comment: You can try and play with several options here. You don't have to use the md5. You can use 0 and 1 column. You can use a different hashing algorithm as well. You can store the binary output of the hash in the column, reducing space requirements. There are many options, I suggest trying out the hash approach and then compare the speed to having a column with 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best option is to allow NULL value on this column, and then to use a where clause like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM q_tasks 
WHERE html IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: That will still be slow without an index.